# ngCookie doesn't get sessionid

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I'm using `ngCookie` and checking existence of `sessionid` to prevent unnecessary authentications. but `$cookie.getAll()` returns all the cookies except `sessionid`.
**More context:**
`sessionid` exist in Resource tab of *Chrome devTools*.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the sessionid cookie being returned is httpOnly meaning you won't be able to access it via JavaScript, only the server can modify it if so.